# Setting the default name of the limit for the iteration Live Template

Tags: java, variables, intellij-idea, iteration, live-templates

In IntelliJ the default template for iteration is

```
for(int $INDEX$ = 0; $INDEX$ < $LIMIT$; $INDEX$++) {
  $END$
}
```

Here `$INDEX$` defaults to `suggestIndexName()` and `$LIMIT$` to an empty string.

I tried to edit this template. What I am trying to do is give `$LIMIT$` a default value using `variableOfType("int")`, but the problem is that this seems to include `i` itself. Is there a way to filter out the `i` from `variableOfType("int")`?